# Microsoft Graph API limitations with SharePoint

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

On a project I have to inject around 100k documents in SharePoint using graph API.
I do not use multi-thread for this application.
Documents are stored in specific folders that are patched and become document set.

The document upload is following steps:

**1. Check if the provided content type exists and columns are correctly passed**
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{siteId}}/lists/{{listId}}/contentTypes?$expand=columns](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7B%7BsiteId%7D%7D/lists/%7B%7BlistId%7D%7D/contentTypes?$expand=columns)

**2. Check if the document set exists or not**
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{siteId}}/lists/{{listId}}/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/ContentType](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7B%7BsiteId%7D%7D/lists/%7B%7BlistId%7D%7D/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/ContentType) eq '"{{documentSetName}}"'

**3. Create folder if not exists**
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{driveId}}/root/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7B%7BdriveId%7D%7D/root/children)

**4. Get sharepoint ids**
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{siteId}}/drives/{{driveId}}/items/{{folderId}}?expand=sharepointids](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7B%7BsiteId%7D%7D/drives/%7B%7BdriveId%7D%7D/items/%7B%7BfolderId%7D%7D?expand=sharepointids)

**5. Patch folder and convert to document set**
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{siteId}}/lists/{{listId}}/items/{{itemId}}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7B%7BsiteId%7D%7D/lists/%7B%7BlistId%7D%7D/items/%7B%7BitemId%7D%7D)

**6. Create document depending on size**

- Create document if < 4Mo
- Create document if > 4Mo by creating session

**7. Change the document content type**

My issue is that after something like 3000 documents sent, I do have a 502 error returned from the application.

Here is my patchRequest implementation :

```
private SharePointDocumentCreateResponse patchRequestHandler(SharePointDocumentCreateRequest request,
                                                             String token,
                                                             String step,
                                                             URL url) throws IOException {
    SharePointDocumentCreateResponse returnValue = new SharePointDocumentCreateResponse();
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    // System.out.println(gson.toJson(request));

    try {
        HttpPatch httpPatch = new HttpPatch(String.valueOf(url));

        // set headers
        httpPatch.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        httpPatch.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPatch.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1");
        httpPatch.setHeader("Prefer", "HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly");

        // créer le payload
        if(request.getStepProcess()!= null) {
            if(request.getStepProcess().equals("patchFolder")) {
                httpPatch.setEntity(new StringEntity(gson.toJson(request.getBodyQuery())));
            } else {
                throw new RequestException(step + " >> Unknown error");
            }
        } else {
            SharePointDocumentCreateRequest updateContentType = new SharePointDocumentCreateRequest();
            ContentTypeParams ct = new ContentTypeParams();
            ct.setId(request.getContentType().getId());
            updateContentType.setContentType(ct);

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            updateContentType.setFields(request.getFieldsValues());
            httpPatch.setEntity(new StringEntity(gson.toJson(updateContentType)));
        }

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPatch);
        final int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        try {
            InputStream responseContent = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(responseContent);

            StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer();
            String tmp;
            while ((tmp = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                json.append(tmp);
            }
            dis.close();

            if (responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK || responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) {
                // System.out.println(responseContent.toString());
                returnValue = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), SharePointDocumentCreateResponse.class);
            } else {
                String errorMessage = step + " >> #patchRequest -> Error! We could not perform the request at" +
                        "\n\tUrl : " + url +
                        "\n\tResponseContent : " + responseContent.toString() +
                        "\n\tError code: " + responseCode +
                        "\n\t => Token: " + token;
                log.error(errorMessage);
                throw new RequestException(errorMessage);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = step + " >> #patchRequest -> Error! We could not perform the request at" +
                    "\n\tUrl : " + url +
                    "\n\tlocalized message : " + e.getLocalizedMessage() +
                    "\n\tError code: " + responseCode +
                    "\n\t => Token: " + token;

            log.error(errorMessage);
            throw new RequestException(errorMessage);
        }
        //returnValue = gson.fromJson(response.getEntity(), SharePointDocumentResponseModel.class);
        // returnValue = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }
    catch (IOException | RequestException e) {
        String errorMessage = step + " >> #patchRequest -> Error! We could not perform the request at" +
                "\n\tUrl : " + url +
                "\n\tlocalized message : " + e.getLocalizedMessage() +
                "\n\t => Token: " + token;
        log.error(errorMessage);
        throw new RequestException(errorMessage);
    }
    httpClient.close();
    return returnValue;

}
```

My questions are the following:

1. Are there any limitations concerning the Microsoft Graph API ?
   number of document sent in an hour, number of calls of the API ...
2. Are there any problems with my patch request code ? If there's an issue with the code, why does it happen after around 3000 documents ?

When i try to call with a get request the url : [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{siteId}}/lists/{{listId}}/items/{{itemId}}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7B%7BsiteId%7D%7D/lists/%7B%7BlistId%7D%7D/items/%7B%7BitemId%7D%7D)
I do have a response. It does mean I do a put call and something is happening during my call.
Apparently, all my issues are coming from this patch folder call.

Comment: Have you tried to implement retry pattern?

Comment: the application is integrated in a workflow and the global application allow to relaunch crashed documents. Anyway, I do not have 1 document sent in error. If i provide 4000 documents, I do have around 1000 of them that throw exception.

Comment: I've experienced 502 bad gateway errors in the past and they tend to occur when the api hangs. For the OneNote-API, that I predominantly deal with, I think there is still a 5000 Notebook (file) limit for certain calls. Once you send your 3000-4000 files do any subsequent calls work? If you delete the files does it then work again? There are definitely limits on number of API calls but you would expect a 429 "Throttled" error.

Answer (score 1):

I can address question 1: Are there any limitations concerning the Graph API?

My main guidance I would recommend is to not spam the service, as there is documentation as well as a video to explain how they throttle their service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling

It's worth handling if you are building out an API to integrate with Graph API.